# Should I send an email to the journal to ask about a submission 4 months ago?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

I submitted a manuscript in December, and it was assigned to an editor in March. It went under review and one reviewer report was ready in late March. I have been waiting for the last two months for the other reports to come in and for a decision, but yesterday the status changed to "editor invited." Does this mean that they changed the editor and are inviting new reviewers as well? Should I send an email to the journal to inquire about this since it has been four months and if they can't find an editor/reviewer then maybe I should resubmit to another journal? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You should discuss this with your advisor or another experienced colleague. It strongly depends on your (sub)field if 4 months is considered too long.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ask the editor. There is no way to know what is happening unless you ask. But over several months, large organizations have personnel changes. Also, early reviews might have indicated that someone else might have been a more appropriate editor. There are lots of possibilities.

But, after four months, you can ask for a status update.

And, don't submit to another journal unless you withdraw the paper from the current submission. I'd guess withdrawing and resubmitting elsewhere is suboptimal since you would be starting the process over again with several months to wait for a decision.